# The best way to parallelize program using OpenMP to ensure that it can scale to make effective use of a modern multi-core processor

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, hpc

I have created a C program to calculates values of the function y(x) = sin(nx) for
n = 1, 2, 3, 4. The constant `M_PI` is defined in the `math.h` header file.

What is the best way to parallelize this program using OpenMP to ensure
that it can scale to make effective use of a modern multi-core processor?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
   const int NPOINTS=1001;
   const int NCURVES=4;
   double dtheta;
   double y[NCURVES][NPOINTS];
   double theta[NPOINTS];

   dtheta = 2*M_PI / ( (float) (NPOINTS-1) );

   for (int n=0; n<NCURVES; n++){
      for(int i=0; i<NPOINTS; i++){
         theta[i] = ( (float) i) * dtheta;
         y[n][i] = sin( ((float) (n+1)) * theta[i]);
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is pretty straightforward since there is no loop dependencies or potential race-conditions. You just need to assign the iterations of the two loops among threads as follows:

```
   #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
   for (int n=0; n<NCURVES; n++){
      for(int i=0; i<NPOINTS; i++){
         theta[i] = ( (float) i) * dtheta;
         y[n][i] = sin( ((float) (n+1)) * theta[i]);
      }
   }
```

You can swap both loops as well:

```
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i=0; i < NPOINTS; i++){
         theta[i] = ((float) i) * dtheta;
         for(int n=0; n < NCURVES; n++){
             y[n][i] = sin( ((float) (n+1)) * theta[i]);
         }
    }
```

You need to test and see which one scales the best.

As pointed out in the comments by [tstanisl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4989451/tstanisl) there is little sense storing the `((float) i) * dtheta` since

> "because modern CPU will compute it much faster than fetching data
> from cache":

```
   #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
   for (int n=0; n<NCURVES; n++){
      for(int i=0; i<NPOINTS; i++){
         y[n][i] = sin( ((float) (n+1)) * ( (float) i) * dtheta);
      }
   }
```

Comment: memorization of `((float) i) * dtheta` makes very little sense because modern CPU will compute it much faster than fetching data from cache

Comment: @tstanisl Thanks for your input I had the same feeling but I was not sure about it